# How to disable the auto discovery of unit-tests in Visual Studio Code Python Module

Tags: visual-studio-code, python-unittest

Working on a big project with `ms-python.python` module of VS-Code, I have to wait for a long time for the unit-test discovery after saving any changes. Also discovering all unit-tests consumes much power on laptop.
Is there any way to disable auto discovery and call it just whenever adding a new test (or remove a one)?

Answer (score 3):

[image: Click on the settings as shown in the image]

Click on settings

```
"python.unitTest.autoTestDiscoverOnSaveEnabled": false
```

And add this line to your PROJECT SETTINGS

This would disable the autotest discovery on every change in your project workspace.

Comment: I need unit-test and the discovery feature. But I don't want to call on every change. Your solution will disable the unit-test.

Comment: Should this be set to `false` to disable auto discovery?

Comment: @mareoraft yes, this should be set to ```false``` to disable auto-discovery. Updated the above answer too. 